# Convert 'String' to Base64 encode of MD5 'String' in c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, base64, md5, password-encryption

How can i Convert my password 'String' to Base64 encode of MD5 'String'. Like this string '**password**' to '**X03MO1qnZdYdgyfeuILPmQ==**'.

Please help me here

OR just let me know the technique that how can i convert this '**password**' to '**X03MO1qnZdYdgyfeuILPmQ==**'. i will code it myself

Comment: in this case btoa('password') = "cGFzc3dvcmQ=" . i need an output of "X03MO1qnZdYdgyfeuILPmQ=="

Comment: Take a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417105/javascript-base-64-decoding-binary-data-doesnt-work)

Comment: Did I understand well, You want encode string **password** using MD5 and then that result to Base64?

Comment: yes you are right. i tried but my answer is different than 'X03MO1qnZdYdgyfeuILPmQ=='

Comment: @ZaidIqbal I posted answer so, try it.

Comment: If you're encoding "password" and obtaining a fixed, known string, you're doing a **bad** job, if your job is to store passwords securely.

Comment: Storing passwords with MD5 is utterly unsafe, especially without a salt. You should switch to a slow hash function with a cost factor, like BCrypt or PBKDF2, please have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14475388/575765);

Answer (score 8):

Ok, there is example (vb.net, I'll try to convert in c# using some online converter) :

```
Dim pwd As String = "password"
Dim hs As System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create
Dim db As Byte() = hs.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pwd))
Dim result As String = Convert.ToBase64String(db)
```

string **password** will result with **X03MO1qnZdYdgyfeuILPmQ==**

Update : *converted to c# using online converter (I hope it's correctly converted)*

```
string pwd = "password";
System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 hs = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create;
byte[] db = hs.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pwd));
string result = Convert.ToBase64String(db);
```