# How can I convert a Base64 encode of MD5 password in javascript

Tags: javascript, hash, base64, ascii

From this stackoverflow question: [Convert 'String' to Base64 encode of MD5 'String' in c# .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33719689/convert-string-to-base64-encode-of-md5-string-in-c-sharp-net) how can I port this code/algorithm to frontend javascript?

From: `password`

To: `X03MO1qnZdYdgyfeuILPmQ==`

I've tried `btoa` etc. but yielded different results

Answer (score 2):

Suggested by [Leyon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3958934/leyon-gudinho) of using Crypto-JS library, I've added a code to convert it to Base64 from Hex output of Crypto-JS. I think this is not the best answer but this helps me, for now.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soLf33xy/)

```
var md5 = function(value) {
  return CryptoJS.MD5(value).toString();
}

function hexToBase64(str) {
  return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,
    str.replace(/\r|\n/g, "").replace(/([\da-fA-F]{2}) ?/g, "0x$1 ").replace(/ +$/, "").split(" "))
  );
}

$("input").keyup(function () {
    var value = $(this).val(),
        hash = md5(value);
    $(".test").html(hash);
    $(".base64").html(hexToBase64(hash));
});
```